# How to know that the keyed window processing will start and has been finished

Tags: apache-flink

I have a keyed window stream processing application(`KeyStream.window.process`), and the window is a 15 minutes tumbling window.

I would like to know when a new window processing will start and when this window processing ends, so that I could use this chance to do some cleanup/initialize work `globally`.

For each window, before the processing kicks off, I would like to do some initializing work, such as truncate a db table (this operation should only occur in one place, this is a global operation that should not be done in the process method).

And when the processing window ends(all the process operator's tasks have been finished), I would like to do some other cleanup work (again, this is a global operation).

I would like to know whether is is possible in flink and how to do it, thanks!

Comment: I am not sure if this is possible at all. But even if it would it seems like a very hacky and dangerous solution honestly. Isn't there a better way to achieve what You want to achieve ?

Comment: If you have a keyed operation, what do you mean by globally? Once per key, once per application? If the latter, how do you determine on which machine to execute that?

Comment: @ArvidHeise So I would like to know that all the sub-tasks in this process operator has been finished, and take this chance to do my init/clean operations.

Comment: @DominikWosiński I agree ,this is a bad practice, but sometimes people may want to know the start and end of a window processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could accomplish this in an operator that follows the window, running with a parallelism of one. This operator will need to detect when a new batch of results begins to arrive from the window, and can do what's needed to close the previous window in the DB and initialize the new one at that time. It can also implement `close()` to do whatever wrap-up is needed if/when the job is ending or being shutdown.

Having done the initialization, this operator can simply forward on all of the events it receives from the window operator, until detecting the beginning of the next window's results.

This operator will need to keep one piece of managed state, namely some sort of identifier for the current window, so it can detect when a new window has begun. The results from the window will need to carry this identifier -- which could just be the window starting or ending timestamp.

You can used Flink's key partitioned state for this state -- you can simply key the stream by a constant. This is normally a bad idea, because it forces the effective parallelism to one (since every event will be assigned the same key), but as that's needed anyway by this (global) operator, that's not an issue.

Given these requirements, this operator could be a `RichFlatMapFunction`, or a `KeyedProcessFunction`. You'll need to use a `KeyedProcessFunction` if you find yourself wanting to use timers to do cleanup.

Comment: Thanks, @David Anderson, I will evaluate your solution, thanks!